# How to convert the C# XML documentation generated by the compiler to some more readable format? like HTML

Tags: c#

I get a custom c# library today with a .dll file and a xml documentation. the xml documentation looks like generated by the compiler with the format like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>some_name_here</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="T:some_name_here">
...
```

Is there any convenient way to covert to file to something more readable, like html? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest running it through the [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/), which can convert your XML documentation into an HTML Help 1 (.chm) file or a website of HTML pages (among other formats).

Comment: super cool! I have found sandcastle, but it seems no update after 2010. SHFB looks better.

Comment: SHFB requires Sandcastle to run, but provides a much user-friendlier interface.

Comment: Still a good answer in 2022, although correct link is now: https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but SHFB can't work with the XML files alone, it needs the built assembly as well.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way is to write an XSLT transform that will generate HTML directly from the XML.

See http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/xml/converting-xml-to-html-using-xsl.html

Comment: Wouldn't XSLT transform the *whole* assembly's documentation into a single HTML file?